# How to prevent CSS animations from moving the rest of my page?

Tags: css, css-animations

I've added an animation to a button using keyframes. The animation is supposed to result in a pulsing effect. The animation appears to be working correctly but when I add text underneath it, the animation causes the text to move also.

Here is a screenshot of the animation
[image]

The 'pulsing' text is being moved up and down as the button itself grows and shrinks.

Here is my related CSS:

```
 **Button num 4 **/
#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1614371999436_9067 .sqs-block-button-element {
  position: relative !important;
  color: black !important;
  background-color: orange !important;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px green;
  animation: demoButtonPulse 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes demoButtonPulse {
    0% {padding: 1.3rem 2.171rem;;
          background: red;}
    50% {padding: 1.43rem 2.3881rem;;
          background: green;
        }
    100% {padding: 1.3rem 2.171rem;;
              background: red;}
  }

#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1614371999436_9067 .sqs-block-button-element:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
  border-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px orange;
}
```

Any idea as to how I can keep the text from moving while the button pulses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I was able to accomplish what you want using scale instead of padding in your keyframes:

```css
.sqs-block-button-element{
  position: relative !important;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: black !important;
  background-color: orange !important;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px green;
  animation: demoButtonPulse 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes demoButtonPulse {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
  }

.sqs-block-button-element:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
  border-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px orange;
}
```

```html
<main>
<button type="submit" class="sqs-block-button-element">
  Call to Action
</button>
    <div>pulsing</div>
</main>
```

The other solution would be to wrap the `button` in a `div` and give the `div` a fixed height:

```css
.sqs-block-button-element{
  position: relative !important;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: black !important;
  background-color: orange !important;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px green;
  animation: demoButtonPulse 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.button-height {
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes demoButtonPulse {
    0% {padding: 1.3rem 2.171rem;;
          background: red;}
    50% {padding: 1.43rem 2.3881rem;;
          background: green;
        }
    100% {padding: 1.3rem 2.171rem;;
              background: red;}
  }

/* @keyframes demoButtonPulse {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
  } */

.sqs-block-button-element:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
  border-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px orange;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="button-height">
<button type="submit" class="sqs-block-button-element">
  Call to Action
</button>
    </div>
    <div>pulsing</div>
</main>
```